# Printer stack on processing - failed to read ppd file

Tags: drivers, lubuntu, 16.04, printing, hp

I need to install a network printer: HP-LaserJet-Pro-MFP-m125nw
on Lubuntu 16.04.

- I have installed HPLIP
- I can see printer with green mark in Printers
- I can send job to printer

But they actually do not print and the job is marked as processing.

Notes:

- Using Simple Scan I can scan any document with success.
- I have notive if I install the printer using USB it works just fine, so I suppose issue is only when try to install the printer on the network

Could you please point me out what could be the issue and how to fix it?

Below the result of  running hp-check:

I see a warning:

`Failed to read /etc/cups/ppd/HP-LaserJet-Pro-MFP-m125nw.ppd ppd file`

---

```
HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.16.3)
Dependency/Version Check Utility ver. 15.1

Copyright (c) 2001-15 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

Note: hp-check can be run in three modes:
1. Compile-time check mode (-c or --compile): Use this mode before compiling the
HPLIP supplied tarball (.tar.gz or .run) to determine if the proper dependencies
are installed to successfully compile HPLIP.                                    
2. Run-time check mode (-r or --run): Use this mode to determine if a distro    
supplied package (.deb, .rpm, etc) or an already built HPLIP supplied tarball   
has the proper dependencies installed to successfully run.                      
3. Both compile- and run-time check mode (-b or --both) (Default): This mode    
will check both of the above cases (both compile- and run-time dependencies).   

Check types:                                                                    
a. EXTERNALDEP - External Dependencies                                          
b. GENERALDEP - General Dependencies (required both at compile and run time)    
c. COMPILEDEP - Compile time Dependencies                                       
d. [All are run-time checks]                                                    
PYEXT SCANCONF QUEUES PERMISSION                                                

Status Types:
    OK
    MISSING       - Missing Dependency or Permission or Plug-in
    INCOMPAT      - Incompatible dependency-version or Plugin-version


---------------
| SYSTEM INFO |
---------------

 Kernel: 4.4.0-22-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 5 16:53:32 UTC 2016 GNU/Linux
 Host: sixpo-ThinkPad-Edge-E440
 Proc: 4.4.0-22-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 5 16:53:32 UTC 2016 GNU/Linux
 Distribution: ubuntu 16.04
 Bitness: 64 bit


-----------------------
| HPLIP CONFIGURATION |
-----------------------

HPLIP-Version: HPLIP 3.16.3
HPLIP-Home: /usr/share/hplip
HPLIP-Installation: Auto installation is supported for ubuntu distro  16.04 version 

Current contents of '/etc/hp/hplip.conf' file:
# hplip.conf.  Generated from hplip.conf.in by configure.

[hplip]
version=3.16.3

[dirs]
home=/usr/share/hplip
run=/var/run
ppd=/usr/share/ppd/hplip/HP
ppdbase=/usr/share/ppd/hplip
doc=/usr/share/doc/hplip
html=/usr/share/doc/hplip-doc
icon=no
cupsbackend=/usr/lib/cups/backend
cupsfilter=/usr/lib/cups/filter
drv=/usr/share/cups/drv
bin=/usr/bin
apparmor=/etc/apparmor.d
# Following values are determined at configure time and cannot be changed.
[configure]
network-build=yes
libusb01-build=no
pp-build=yes
gui-build=yes
scanner-build=yes
fax-build=yes
dbus-build=yes
cups11-build=no
doc-build=yes
shadow-build=no
hpijs-install=yes
foomatic-drv-install=yes
foomatic-ppd-install=yes
foomatic-rip-hplip-install=no
hpcups-install=yes
cups-drv-install=yes
cups-ppd-install=no
internal-tag=3.16.3
restricted-build=no
ui-toolkit=qt4
qt3=no
qt4=yes
policy-kit=yes
lite-build=no
udev_sysfs_rules=no
hpcups-only-build=no
hpijs-only-build=no
apparmor_build=no


Current contents of '/var/lib/hp/hplip.state' file:
[plugin]
installed = 1
eula = 1
version = 3.16.3



Current contents of '~/.hplip/hplip.conf' file:
[last_used]
device_uri = hp:/net/HP_LaserJet_Pro_MFP_M125nw?ip=10.0.0.5

[installation]
date_time = 05/29/16 10:34:59
version = 3.16.3


 <Package-name>        <Package-Desc>      <Required/Optional> <Min-Version> <Installed-Version> <Status>   <Comment>

--------------------------
|  External Dependencies |
--------------------------

 cups                 CUPS - Common Unix Printing System                           REQUIRED        1.1             2.1.3           OK         'CUPS Scheduler is running'
 scanimage            scanimage - Shell scanning program                           OPTIONAL        1.0             1.0.25          OK         -
 xsane                xsane - Graphical scanner frontend for SANE                  OPTIONAL        0.9             0.999           OK         -
 network              network -wget                                                OPTIONAL        -               1.17.1          OK         -
 policykit            PolicyKit - Administrative policy framework                  OPTIONAL        -               0.105           OK         -
 avahi-utils          avahi-utils                                                  OPTIONAL        -               0.6.32          OK         -
 gs                   GhostScript - PostScript and PDF language interpreter and previewer REQUIRED        7.05            9.18            OK         -
 dbus                 DBus - Message bus system                                    REQUIRED        -               1.10.6          OK         -

-------------------------
|  General Dependencies |
-------------------------

 python3-dbus         Python DBus - Python bindings for DBus                       REQUIRED        0.80.0          1.2.0           OK         -
 python3-reportlab    Reportlab - PDF library for Python                           OPTIONAL        2.0             3.3.0           OK         -
 cups-image           CUPS image - CUPS image development files                    REQUIRED        -               2.1.3           OK         -
 python3-xml          Python XML libraries                                         REQUIRED        -               2.1.0           OK         -
 libpthread           libpthread - POSIX threads library                           REQUIRED        -               b'2.23'         OK         -
 cups-devel           CUPS devel- Common Unix Printing System development files    REQUIRED        -               2.1.3           OK         -
 libusb               libusb - USB library                                         REQUIRED        -               1.0             OK         -
 python3-devel        Python devel - Python development files                      REQUIRED        2.2             3.5.1           OK         -
 libjpeg              libjpeg - JPEG library                                       REQUIRED        -               -               OK         -
 python3-pil          PIL - Python Imaging Library (required for commandline scanning with hp-scan) OPTIONAL        -               1.1.7           OK         -
 python3X             Python 2.2 or greater - Python programming language          REQUIRED        2.2             3.5.1           OK         -
 python3-pyqt4-dbus   PyQt 4 DBus - DBus Support for PyQt4                         OPTIONAL        4.0             4.11.4          OK         -
 python3-pyqt4        PyQt 4- Qt interface for Python (for Qt version 4.x)         REQUIRED        4.0             4.11.4          OK         -
 sane                 SANE - Scanning library                                      REQUIRED        -               1.0.25          OK         -
 sane-devel           SANE - Scanning library development files                    REQUIRED        -               1.0.25          OK         -
 python3-notify2      Python libnotify - Python bindings for the libnotify Desktop notifications OPTIONAL        -               -               OK         -
 libcrypto            libcrypto - OpenSSL cryptographic library                    REQUIRED        -               1.0.2           OK         -
 libnetsnmp-devel     libnetsnmp-devel - SNMP networking library development files REQUIRED        5.0.9           5.7.3           OK         -

---------------
|  COMPILEDEP |
---------------

 gcc                  gcc - GNU Project C and C++ Compiler                         REQUIRED        -               5.3.1           OK         -
 libtool              libtool - Library building support services                  REQUIRED        -               2.4.6           OK         -
 make                 make - GNU make utility to maintain groups of programs       REQUIRED        3.0             4.1             OK         -

----------------------
|  Python Extentions |
----------------------

 cupsext              CUPS-Extension                                               REQUIRED        -               3.16.3          OK         -
 hpmudext             IO-Extension                                                 REQUIRED        -               3.16.3          OK         -

-----------------------
|  Scan Configuration |
-----------------------

 scanext              Scan-SANE-Extension                                          REQUIRED        -               3.16.3          OK         -
'/etc/sane.d/dll.d/hpaio' not found.
 hpaio                HPLIP-SANE-Backend                                           REQUIRED        -               3.16.3          OK         'hpaio found in /etc/sane.d/dll.conf'

-----------------------
|  Other Dependencies |
-----------------------


------------------------------
| DISCOVERED SCANNER DEVICES |
------------------------------

device `hpaio:/net/HP_LaserJet_Pro_MFP_M125nw?ip=10.0.0.5' is a Hewlett-Packard HP_LaserJet_Pro_MFP_M125nw all-in-one


--------------------------
| DISCOVERED USB DEVICES |
--------------------------

No devices found.

---------------------------------
| INSTALLED CUPS PRINTER QUEUES |
---------------------------------


HP-LaserJet-Pro-MFP-m125nw
--------------------------
Type: Printer
Device URI: hp:/net/HP_LaserJet_Pro_MFP_M125nw?ip=10.0.0.5
PPD: /etc/cups/ppd/HP-LaserJet-Pro-MFP-m125nw.ppd
warning: Failed to read /etc/cups/ppd/HP-LaserJet-Pro-MFP-m125nw.ppd ppd file
PPD Description: 
Printer status: printer HP-LaserJet-Pro-MFP-m125nw now printing HP-LaserJet-Pro-MFP-m125nw-6.  enabled since Ne 29. květen 2016,Processing page 1...
Required plug-in status: Installed
Communication status: Good


--------------
| PERMISSION |
--------------

No errors or warnings.

Done.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This warning means that the **hp-check** script doesn't have the permission to read this file.

You can simply change the permissions like this (open a terminal):

```
$ sudo chmod 644 /etc/cups/ppd/HP-LaserJet-Pro-MFP-m125nw.ppd
```

It will give read permission to everyone, and read/write to root.

Comment: Now if I try to print something I am getting the info: Could not start printer.
Please check your printer configuration.

Answer (score 6):

I have an HP printer PhotoSmart and had the same problem...
I went into /etc/cups/ppd/ and modified the permission of my ppd file (root permission needed):
It was 
Owner Root Read and write
- Group lp Read only
- Other No right       I changed that last permission into Read only
And it did the trick so far!
Good luck!

Comment: And for noobs like me:   cd /etc/cups/ppd; ls -la #view permissions;
 sudo chmod 754 HP_LaserJet_4000.ppd; ls -la #view changed permission, should be "-rwxr-xr--"