# Failed to read ppd file but printer is working well

Tags: hplip

I have an HP printer. It works well.
But on running
`hp-check`
it shows

> warning: Failed to read /etc/cups/ppd/DeskJet-5820-series.ppd ppd file

Do I have to worry about this?
What do I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you have the same problem as [Printer stack on processing - failed to read ppd file](https://askubuntu.com/q/778970/707756)

You just need to change the permissions of read / write of the file

```
$ sudo chmod 644 /etc/cups/ppd/HP-LaserJet-Pro-MFP-m125nw.ppd
```

I just followed these 2 answers
[answer1](https://askubuntu.com/a/994017/707756), [answer2](https://askubuntu.com/a/808013/707756)

Don't worry so much and give others a headache.

Comment: You have just introduced a security hole in your printing system. The hp-check message is only a warning and probably should be attended to by upstream HPLIP if they could be bothered to do so. It is nothing for a user to get worried about. Your "fix" is not a fix.