# Why it is such a big problem to use HP printer in Ubuntu 21.04?

Tags: printing, hp, 21.04, hplip

I always used the hp printers with Ubuntu without a problems. Probably from version 20 I had a problems.  Now I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 21.04, new printer ( HP deskjet plus 6075 ) new usb cable and stil have a problems with printing.

[I have made :](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056077/how-to-install-latest-hplip-on-my-ubuntu-to-support-my-hp-printer-and-or-scanner)

```
sh hplip-3.21.6.run
```

without problems/errors. Then

hp-check

```
HP_DeskJet_Plus_6000_series_3BB95C_
-----------------------------------
Type: Unknown
Device URI: implicitclass://HP_DeskJet_Plus_6000_series_3BB95C_/
PPD: /etc/cups/ppd/HP_DeskJet_Plus_6000_series_3BB95C_.ppd
warning: Failed to read /etc/cups/ppd/HP_DeskJet_Plus_6000_series_3BB95C_.ppd ppd file
PPD Description: 
Printer status: printer HP_DeskJet_Plus_6000_series_3BB95C_ is idle.  enabled since sob, 10 lip 2021, 13:00:41
warning: Printer is not HPLIP installed. Printers must use the hp: or hpfax: CUPS backend for HP-Devices.

HP_DeskJet_Plus_6000_series_3BB95C_USB_
---------------------------------------
Type: Unknown
Device URI: implicitclass://HP_DeskJet_Plus_6000_series_3BB95C_USB_/
PPD: /etc/cups/ppd/HP_DeskJet_Plus_6000_series_3BB95C_USB_.ppd
warning: Failed to read /etc/cups/ppd/HP_DeskJet_Plus_6000_series_3BB95C_USB_.ppd ppd file
PPD Description: 
Printer status: printer HP_DeskJet_Plus_6000_series_3BB95C_USB_ is idle.  enabled since sob, 10 lip 2021, 13:03:22
warning: Printer is not HPLIP installed. Printers must use the hp: or hpfax: CUPS backend for HP-Devices.


--------------
| PERMISSION |
--------------

USB             None                           Required        -        -        OK       Node:'/dev/bus/usb/003/011' Perm:'  root  lp rw- rw- rw- rw- rw- r--'
 
-----------
| SUMMARY |
-----------

Missing Required Dependencies
-----------------------------
None

Missing Optional Dependencies
-----------------------------
None


Total Errors: 0
Total Warnings: 2
```

[so I have made](https://askubuntu.com/questions/778970/printer-stack-on-processing-failed-to-read-ppd-file)

```
sudo chmod 644 /etc/cups/ppd/HP_DeskJet_Plus_6000_series_3BB95C_USB_.ppd
```

```
lpstat -v
device for DeskJet_Plus_6000: ipp://HP%20DeskJet%20Plus%206000%20series%20%5B3BB95C%5D%20(USB)._ipp._tcp.local/
device for HP_DeskJet_Plus_6000_series_3BB95C_: implicitclass://HP_DeskJet_Plus_6000_series_3BB95C_/
device for HP_DeskJet_Plus_6000_series_3BB95C_USB_: implicitclass://HP_DeskJet_Plus_6000_series_3BB95C_USB_/
```

Prints information page

```
hp-setup

HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.21.6)
Printer/Fax Setup Utility ver. 9.0

Copyright (c) 2001-18 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

Searching... (bus=usb, search=(None), desc=0)
error:  Device error:  Unknown/invalid device-uri field (4).
```

```
 hp-setup -i my_prn_ip
```

prints  test page

Now I can print from gedit. But it took me a few months to print from Ubuntu.

question : **Is there general problem with hplip or Ubuntu is not user friendly?**

============= edit 1 ======================

I have also used [apt-get](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070470/how-should-i-install-hplip-binary-proprietary-plugin-driver-for-my-hp-printer-or) to install hplip and hp-setup  with no effect.

============= edit 2 ====================
I have rename a question : the problem is solved, but the reason of the problem is interesting for me.

===edit 3=====

still problems: https://bugs.launchpad.net/hplip/+bug/1939942

Comment: @24601 yes but hplip has drivers for it : "HP DeskJet Plus 6000 series 3.20.5 Yes Yes Full Color Yes No USB,Network" from 
  https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index

Comment: my bad... I saw 600 not 6000

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I install HPLIP binary/proprietary plugin/driver for my HP printer or printer+scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070470/how-should-i-install-hplip-binary-proprietary-plugin-driver-for-my-hp-printer-or)

Comment: @Norbert I have used accepted answers. The problem is that in prevoius versions of Ubuntu installing hp printer was automatic. Now I have to spend many days to solve . It is not good result for the ubuntu desktop.

Comment: Use ipp-usb: https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/pzz/xUbuntu_20.04/amd64/

Comment: Hp printers are normally well supported. I doubt this can be summed up to a general problem with such printers.

Comment: @cipricus This is an example that HP is not well suported. HPLIP shows no errors, buyut the pronter does not work without painful installation.  I ask why ?

Comment: Printer support is an old problem in Linux (the cause being the printer manufacturers when they make a new printer they don't always provide a new Linux driver). But from my experience HP printers are generally better supported than others -let's say Canon. - On the other hand printer support in Linux has improved overall greatly in the last years, that's why I say I doubt you can extract a general rule the way you do: if support for your new HP printer is bad in Linux that's bad luck: support for other brands is worse.

Comment: (For example, my wifi HP printer is instantly recognized and added once both devices are connected to the same wifi, without the need for any manual installation. Just lucky I guess.)

Comment: https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/07/install-latest-hplip-ubuntu-20-04-fix/

Comment: @cipricus. I think that earlier I used a pronter thru USG cable. Now the printer is using wi-fi in many tasks. I have an phoine applications which sometimes gives me more info then from the computer. Maybe  this is a cause: more functions and more connections.